# C# IEnumerable<T> - is this a "marker interface"?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

I realize that `IEnumerable<T>` has been discussed quite a bit on this forum.

When you make a call to something that returns an IEnumerable of any type of object, you are not getting back a known concrete implementation of anything.  If you inspect the returned data in your debugger (or calling `GetType()` on the returned collection), its type is simply `IEnumerable<MyClass>` (unless of course we materialize it by calling `ToList()`, `ToArray()` et al).

I am also well aware that if we are creating a class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, we have to implement the `GetEnumerator()` method ourselves.

But how does the framework/runtime handle this under the hood?  For example, even in a trivial case like `IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)`, we know that at *some point* during the execution chain, a concrete implementation of `GetEnumerator()` is being created and called, even though we aren't implementing that method ourselves.

Is Microsoft treating this as a marker interface?  In other words - does the runtime, upon encountering/processing a method in our code that returns an IEnumerable, treat it as metadata and create/inject some kind of default implementation?

Technically speaking, marker interfaces are (arguably) a code smell, since according to OOP principles an interface is supposed to be a mere contract or template and should not actually *do* anything (except enforce that contract upon classes implementing it).

But in the case of `IEnumerable<T>`, there are clearly some things being done under the covers.  If you examine the `numbers` variable in a debugger in my trivial example above, you will see that it contains actual, concrete, callable members which must have been implemented somewhere.

For example: if you call `GetEnumerator()` on any instance of an IEnumerable, what *should* happen (if MS was adhering to the strict definition of the OOP concept of interfaces) is some kind of exception (i.e., "Hey, I'm just an interface, I just *declare* that method as part of the contract, I don't actually contain an implementation of it and I have no idea what to do with it").  But instead, it gets called successfully.

What is really going on?

Comment: _"(or calling GetType() on the returned collection), its type is simply IEnumerable<MyClass>"_ That's incorrect. For example, `Enumerable.Range()` returns an object of type RangeIterator. You can also test it with a custom method that returns any concrete type that implements IEnumerable<T>: https://rextester.com/AJVZ68662

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine It actually uses a method called RangeIterator that returns an IEnumerable<int> via `yield return start + i;`

Comment: @hijinxbassist No, it returns an object of type RangeIterator (which is a private type). You can see it [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Range.cs,24). Also, as mentioned above, this isn't specific to Enumerable.Range. GetType will always tell you the concrete type (if there's one).

Comment: I was literally looking at source [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html) which has the definition as `return RangeIterator(start, count);` and `static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, int count)`.  My mistake though, not sure where this other version came from..  Oh, its from Core, perhaps that is the difference...

Answer (score 0):

Something that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` is actually returning a class that implements that interface.

For instance take your example (`Enumerable.Range`), here is the source code

```
 public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int count)
    {
        long max = ((long)start) + count - 1;
        if (count < 0 || max > int.MaxValue)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.count);
        }
 
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return Empty<int>();
        }
 
        return new RangeIterator(start, count); <<<<=====
    }
```

see https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Range.cs,fda9d378095a6464

following `RangeIterator` declaration stack

```
 private sealed partial class RangeIterator : Iterator<int>
```

and

```
 internal abstract class Iterator<TSource> : IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerator<TSource>
```

no magic, `Enumerable.Range` returns an instance of `RangeIterator`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`

The point of interfaces is that the caller doesn't need to know anything about what's going on behind the interface, other than the returned object implements it. So the caller can call the interface methods knowing that they will work

reading the LINQ source is very informative, use that source browser its amazingly useful https://source.dot.net/

Comment: thanks for the insight on `Enumerable.Range()`.  So in this case it actually *is* returning a concrete class!  I guess I'll need to look at the LINQ source to find out what happens in non-trivial cases, e.g., returning records from a database or API call.

Comment: @QBBryant they all return concrete classes that implement that interface. Reminder :  It is not possible to instantiate an interface, so you are always returning a class object that implements the interface. Even if you go `return (IEnumerable<T>)obj` - ie cast the object to the interface you are still really returning that object

Comment: Well, it _has_ to return an instance of a concrete class, because you can't instantiate an interface. So in _all_ cases that's what you'll get.

Comment: I would also note that returning `IEnumerable` allows the method to choose between different implementations for performance reasons. For example, by returning `Enumerable.Empty`. https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Select.cs,36